# Booting off an iso file or efi file on an UEFI-enabled computer with windows on it

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, iso-image, android-x86

The Scenario is something like this:
I have an UEFI-Enabled computer with a clean installation of Windows 10 on it. I would like to dualboot it with Android x86 but without using any external usb drive. In short , i would like to boot from an iso file that is present in my hard disk, or alternatively extract the iso and boot from the appropriate .efi file.

Is it possible to achieve any of the options? If yes , then how?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would re-evaluate the use case - du you really want a dual boot or rather a VM like with virtual box. The performance penalty of virtualisation is usually not a problem, because most android applications are lightweight on IO and CPU requirements.

For a dual boot you need some kind of boot manager. The most common one (besides the windows-specific bootloader) is GRUB 2.

here is one answer from the askubuntu network https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014944/adding-android-x86-to-grub2 . As super user wants to have the answer right here, a quote:

> First type sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom in a terminal and add this
> boot sequence to the file.
>
> menuentry "Lineage x86" {   set root='(hdX,Y)'   linux
> /cm-x86-14.1-rc1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0
> androidboot.selinux=permissive acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode
> SRC=/cm-x86-14.1-rc1   initrd /cm-x86-14.1-rc1/initrd.img }
>
> hdX,Y here is the name of your partition where Android is installed.
> My installed partition is sda9, so the entry will be hd0,9. For sdb5
> the entry would be hd1,5 and so on.
>
> If you haven't installed cm-x86-14.1-rc1 but some other version,
> replace the lines containing "cm-x86-14.1-rc1" with your version.
>
> Then save the file and run sudo update-grub in terminal.
>
> A new working GRUB menu entry for your new androidx86 should be
> available at the next boot.
>
> PS: androidboot.selinux=permissive is necessary for androidx86 version >=7.0